# How to correctly fetch this stylesheet and include it in the head of my html document?

Tags: html, css, ajax, append

I'd like to use a style sheet from Wikipedia. For that, I'm fetching this style sheet. When trying to
pass the url fetched using ajax to the head of my html document, the url retrieved behave unexpectedly.

First, I simply try to use the url as it is fetched :

```
var stylesheetElem = doc.querySelector('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');
```

Here is the full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- testing purpose file, used for trying to print a correctly formatted wikipedia page -->

<html>
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> game setup </title> <!-- Titre de l'onglet -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:white;">

<div class='container'>
    <h1 id="title">MiniWiki</h1>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>

<script>   
function loadPage() {
    "use strict";
    var url, doc;
    console.log("IN LOADPAGE")
    url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org:443/api/rest_v1/page/html/' + 'Ancient_Egypt';
    // fetch the article data
    return $.ajax(url).then(function (data) {
        doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(data, 'text/html');
        // Use mediawiki content stylesheet
        var stylesheetElem = doc.querySelector('head link[rel="stylesheet"]');      
        console.log("SHOW stylesheetElem");
        console.log(stylesheetElem);     
        $('head').append(stylesheetElem);
        
        //Update content
        var contentElem = document.getElementById('content');
        var $content = $(contentElem).empty();
        Array.from(doc.body.attributes).forEach(function (attr) {
            $content.attr(attr.name, attr.value);
        });
        $content.append(Array.from(doc.body.children));
    });
}
   
loadPage();
</script>
```

In this case, the url fetched is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/w/load.php?lang=en&modulening.con...%7Cext.cite.styles&only=styles&skin=vector">
```

I was expecting that it would also include **https://en.wikipedia.org/** at the beginning of the url like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?lang=en&modulening.con...%7Cext.cite.styles&only=styles&skin=vector">
```

Since it dit not, I thought I could add it myself by simply adding this line of code just
before the line

**console.log("SHOW stylesheetElem");**

```
stylesheetElem.href = "http://en.wikipedia.org" + stylesheetElem.href
```

when printing the stylesheetElem url, this unexpectedly returns the following url :

```
http://en.wikipedia.orgfile//en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?...kin=vector
```

What happened here ? Why didn't I get the following correct url ?

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/load.php?...kin=vector
```

Answer (score 0):

The dots (`...`) indicate that the developer tools have left out part of the url. You copy that instead of the real url, which you can see when you do "View Page Source":

```
/w/load.php?lang=en&amp;modules=ext.uls.interlanguage%7Cext.visualEditor.desktopArticleTarget.noscript%7Cext.wikimediaBadges%7Cskins.vector.styles.legacy&amp;only=styles&amp;skin=vector
```

Comment: I let the dots intentionnally to avoid copying the very lenghty url and in the hope of not overloading my question. If however you think it would add clarity to copy the whole url returned I'll do it.